# change first row tds width with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to update first row width with JavaScript,
I have multiple tables

```
<table page="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>aaaa</td><td>bbbbb</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cccc</td><td>ddddd</td></tr>
  ....
 </tbody>
</table>
<table page="2">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>eeee</td><td>fffff</td></tr>
  <tr><td>gggg</td><td>hhhhh</td></tr>
  ....
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and an array

```
var cw = ["100","500"];
```

i am trying to create a function that will change only the tds from first row inside each table, so the end result should be

```
<table page="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td style="width:100px;">aaaa</td><td style="width:500px;">bbbbb</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cccc</td><td>ddddd</td></tr>
  ....
 </tbody>
</table>
<table page="2">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td style="width:100px;">eeee</td><td style="width:500px;">fffff</td></tr>
  <tr><td>gggg</td><td>hhhhh</td></tr>
  ....
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Since i only started using JavaScript i don't know best way to do things, yet, so i put this jsfiddle together from different examples, the problem is that i will have a lot of tables in one page (around 300) and i would like to know if this is the best way to do it:

```
var cw = ["100","500"];
var i,j,col;
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
for(i = 0;i<tables.length;i++) {
 for ( j = 0, col; col = tables[i].rows[0].cells[j]; j++) {
  col.style.width = cw[j]+'px';
 }
}
```

i am afraid that 2 loops will make the browser unresponsive or slow, so can this be done safer with JavaScript or jquery?
Also i need this to work on IE, Chrome and Firefox
Thanks

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxk117yr/) to test this. Despite having a TON of tables, and making jsfiddle pretty laggy, it still completes relatively quickly

Comment: any way to make it faster?

Comment: My browser was timing it at 13ms, which is pretty darn fast (and for thousands of tables). Making this into jQuery would only make it slower.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will go with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is an example of how it should work

```js
var size = ["100px", "500px"];
var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:first-child');

for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  tr[i].firstElementChild.style.width = size[0];
  tr[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').style.width = size[1];
}
```

```css
td {
  background: yellow;
}

// Background for showing purpose only!
```

```html
<table page="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>aaaa</td><td>bbbbb</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cccc</td><td>ddddd</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>


<table page="2">
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>eeee</td><td>fffff</td></tr>
  <tr><td>gggg</td><td>hhhhh</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, thank you, i have made a more complicated example and it seems your approach is the winner :) i got 23 (ms) with my version, 80 ms with jquery version and 14 ms with yours, so i will accept it as answer, one more question, i was having different number of columns, and i did this modification, is this safe? or can i do it better somehow? 
     var tr = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr:first-child');
     for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      cols = tr[i].children;
      for(j=0; j<cols.length ;j++) {
       cols[j].style.width = size[j];
     }
   }   Thank you

Comment: looks fine, just add `var` declaration in each of the `for` loops init. `for (var i = 0...)` and such (good practice)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be able to get away from using two loops.  One to go through each table and find the first row and the second to apply the widths to each td.  Here's my jQuery version:

```
function assignWidths(arr){
    $('table').each(function(){
       var firstRowTds = $(this).find('tr').eq(0).children('td');
       firstRowTds.each(function(i){
           $(this).css('width', arr[i] + 'px');
       });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i added it to jsfiddle [link]https://jsfiddle.net/wyzixg/fxk117yr/4/ and it seems to be way slower, nice function tho :)